# A Desert Riddle

Tags: riddle, word

I am a drug without a name.
If you get high on me, you will suffer from delusions of grandeur.
I am best consumed on an empty stomach.

You will find one of me in the most insignificant town.

If I am dark, I will be successful in my goals, despite what you might think.
And if I am a different color, well, that is something else entirely.

If you ever want to stop or slow down, I'll be yours and you can just hold me.

All of these things are true because it's me that's telling you.

PS: Feel free to take me out for a drink sometime, I won't commit to anything though.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> You are a horse.

As for having no name,

> Songs have been written about that (and in the desert no less). 
>  
>  I didn't catch the 'drug' reference myself, but apparently 'horse' has been used as slang for heroin, which resulted in the song being banned from many radio stations (see link helpfully provided by puzzledPig below).  Presently stuck in my head despite lyricist's (sober or otherwise) habit of filling out the meter with precious little regard for semantics.

If you have such delusions you should

> get down from your high horse

One is very hungry indeed if they are

> so hungry they could eat a horse.

A dismissably-small village might be called a

> one-horse town

A contender who succeeds against the odds is often referred to as

> a dark horse.

While an entirely distinct matter might be referred to as

> a horse of a different color.

Someone who is acting too hastily might be asked to

> hold their horses.

And something is quite a bit more likely to be true if you hear it

> straight from the horse's mouth.

And of course

> you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make it drink.

So...

> Has anyone offered their kingdom for you?  If they begged enough, perhaps they could ride if you were a wish. Or perhaps it will never happen, all for the want of your shoe-nail... ^_^

Comment: Your answer is correct . As you would guess I am looking for all the lines to be explained, so I will keep this puzzle open until such time.

Comment: Maybe check out this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Horse_with_No_Name#Reception

Comment: I am looking for something else for the consumption bit

Comment: "So hungry I could eat a [CENSORED]"

Comment: Beat me to the realization by seconds...fits the rest of the pattern much better.

Comment: I had more racy (pun intended) lines but I decided against it

Comment: also puzzledPig’s observation is actually what I intended for that.

Comment: Ha, curious, in my country we normally eat them :D

Comment: During the IKEA meatball fiasco years ago (can google it if you didn’t know/remember) is the time when it became clear to me (and probably a lot of people) how taboo foods vary by culture and country.

Comment: *nods*  But while one might be accustomed to eating that, the amount indicated by the idiom is still rather daunting. @_@

Comment: Could you update your answer to account for the information gleaned from a link in these comments?

Comment: I think your bit of interesting trivia might be incorrect. There is a different expression from which this phrase is derived (see Shakespeare) that would more appropriately fit the description you've given.

Comment: Possibly ill-informed speculation expunged.